# Oracle 12c in Docker - Can connect via Oracle SQL Developer, but cannot via SQLPlus

Tags: oracle, docker, sqlplus

I spinned up a docker container with Oracle 12c using this command:

```
docker run 
-d -p 1521:1521 
--name oracle
container-registry.oracle.com/database/enterprise:12.2.0.1
```

After which I can happily connect to it with Oracle SQL Developer under *sys* user as *sysdba* providing the default values for password and SID:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDH1u.png)

But if I open the terminal and type `$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus / as sysdba` then I get the message: `Connected to an idle instance.` and when I try entering any SQL I get `ORA-01034: ORACLE not available`.

Am I doing it wrong?

Inside the container I've got such values for environment variables:

```
ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1
ORACLE_SID=ORCL
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

I tried specifying the credentials and SID explicitly `$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus sys/Oradoc_db1@ORCLCDB as sysdba` but in this case I don't get any response whatsoever.

Comment: Generally you get this error when your ORACLE_HOME is incorrect. Double check it. If you have trouble, you might get the pid of ora_pmon_ORCL process and then do "strings /proc/[pid]/environ | grep ORACLE_HOME" to see what the real home is. Also make sure you are exporting those variables so sqlplus can see them.

Comment: @PaulW The actual value is **/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1** 

`sh-4.2$ ps -aux | grep ora_pmon_ORCL
oracle      47  0.0  0.0 1736836 61584 ?       Ss   15:54   0:00 ora_pmon_ORCLCDB
oracle    4872  0.0  0.0   9060   896 pts/0    S+   18:40   0:00 grep ora_pmon_ORCL
sh-4.2$ strings /proc/47/environ | grep ORACLE_HOME
ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1`

Comment: Looks like ORACLE_HOME is set correctly.

Comment: Did you install the oracle client properly?

Comment: It looks like your instance name is ORCLCDB, not ORCL. Set the ORACLE_SID to ORCLCDB and give it a try. Make sure your env vars are exported.

Comment: @PaulW thank you very much! I specified ORACLE_SID=ORCLCDB and now it works. I typed `$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus / as sysdba` and now I'm able to execute SQL.
The whole command to lanch a container `docker run -d -p 1521:1521 --name oracle --env ORACLE_SID=ORCLCDB container-registry.oracle.com/database/enterprise:12.2.0.1` 
Ps. It's kind of ambiguity when it comes to default value for ORACLE_SID. The environment variable was set to ORCL, but in order to to connect via Oracle SQL Developer I had to specify ORCLCDB.